# TypeError: props.onDeleteClick is not a function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-router

I'm very new to React and I'm trying to make my Delete and Edit button work. But it's giving me this error "TypeError: props.onDeleteClick is not a function"

```
import React from "react";
import Person from "./Person";
import * as UserService from "../services/userServices";

class People extends React.Component
{
    state = {
        template: [],
        // editperson: ""
    };

    componentDidMount(){
        this.onShowPeople();
    }

    // Delete Button function

    onDeleteClick = myId => {
        console.log(myId);
    }

    onDeleteError = errr => {
        console.log(errr)
    };

    onShowPeople = () => {
        UserService
        .showAllPeople()
        .then(this.onDisplaySuccess)
        .catch(this.onDisplayError)
    }

    onDisplaySuccess = res => {
        console.log("Success!")
        console.log(res.item.pagedItems)

        this.setState({
            template: res.item.pagedItems.map(this.renderPersonTemplate)
        });
    }

    onDisplayError = err => console.log("Display Error");

    renderPersonTemplate = person => {
        return <Person person={person} key={person.id}/>;
    }

    render()
    {
        return (
            <React.Fragment>
                <div className="container">
                    <div className="template">
                        {this.state.template}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}
```

export default People;[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOTEg.png)

I just wanted to delete this from my page and from the server.

Comment: I'm just guessing here, but does your `<Person>` component expect an `onDeleteClick` prop? You are only passing `person` and `key` in `renderPersonTemplate`.

Comment: I don't see where you're passing it as a prop or trying to invoke it. Is there another component involved?

Comment: @Dylan yes, i posted a picture of my other code. Please help me.

Comment: @ChrisB. Yes, i posted the picture below my codes. Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Person` component references the following props: `onEditClick` (line 8), `onDeleteClick` (line 12), and `person` (various lines)`. That means when you render a`` you'll need to pass all of those props e.g.

```
<Person person={...} onEditClick={...} onDeleteClick={...} />
```

But you are missing the `onEditClick` and `onDeleteClick` when you render a `<Person>` in your `People` component's `renderPersonTemplate` function.

You defined an `onDeleteClick` function on your `People` component, but that doesn't magically get passed anywhere. You need to explicitly do that yourself. Also, you need to define an `onEditClick` function somewhere so you can pass that too.

```
class People {
   /* ... existing code ... */

  // Delete Button function
  onDeleteClick = myId => {
    console.log('deleting', myId);
  }

  // add this Edit Button function
  onEditClick = myId => {
    console.log('editing', myId);
  }

  renderPersonTemplate = person => {
    return <Person 
      key={person.id} 
      person={person} 
      onEditClick={this.onEditClick} // add this
      onDeleteClick={this.onDeleteClick} // add this
    />;
  }

  /* ... */
}
```

The reason you got the type error is because you weren't passing any `onDeleteClick` with the `<Person>`, so inside the `Person` function, `props.onDeleteClick` was `undefined` instead of being a function as your code expected.

Comment: thank you! This got rid of my error. but when i press delete it doesn't get deleted from my page and my database. how do i do this in my code?

Comment: Fill in you `onDeleteClick` function with code that will do those things. If you need help figuring out how to do that, I recommend asking a new question.

Comment: will do. Thank you again for your help!